# DataNucleus JDO on MySQL fails with FK violation on 1:1 relations

Tags: mysql, jdo, datanucleus, google-cloud-sql

I have issues persisting a simple 2 classes on DataNucleus 3.1.3 on MySQL, where DataNucleus seems to create invalid foreign-keys, ending up in a "foreign key constraint fails" -exception from database.

Here my classes:

```
// datastore since i dont care about identity here
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.DATASTORE)
class A {
    @Persistent
    int x;
    @Persistent
    int y;
}

// identity type:application here to enable id lookups
@PersistenceCapable
class B {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.NATIVE)
    long id;

    @Persistent
    double longitude;
    @Persistent
    double latitude;
    // simple 1:1 unidirectional
    @Persistent
    A a;
}
```

The schemaTool created the tables (InnoDB) which looks good, but an insert fails, here the logs:

```
12:54:11,369 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - INSERT INTO `A` (`X`,`Y`) VALUES (<1>,<1>)
12:54:11,387 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist] - Execution Time = 18 ms (number of rows = 1)
12:54:11,398 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist] - Object "foo.A@624af1e" was inserted in the datastore and was given strategy value of "3"
12:54:11,403 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Closing PreparedStatement "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ParamLoggingPreparedStatement@6f5ba238"
12:54:11,404 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - INSERT INTO `B` (`LONGITUDE`,`LATITUDE`,`A_A_ID_OID`) VALUES (<0.5099776394799052>,<0.6191090630996077>,<51>)
12:54:11,419 WARN  [DataNucleus.Datastore.Persist]  ... Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xperimental`.`B`, CONSTRAINT `B_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`A_A_ID_OID`) REFERENCES `A` (`A_ID`))
```

Looking at the logs on lines (3) and (5) its very suspicious that an insert into table A returned a PK of "3" but DataNucleus instead uses a value of "51" as FK on A when inserting data into table B which causes the violation.

Where is the issue? Thanks

**UPDATE: the resources**

*Class A*

```
package jdotest.a;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdentityType;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;

@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.DATASTORE)
public class A {
  @Persistent
  private int x;
  @Persistent
  private int y;

  public int getX() {
    return x;
  }

  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }
}
```

*Class B*

```
package jdotest.b;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

import jdotest.a.A;

@PersistenceCapable
public class B {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.NATIVE)
  long   id;

  @Persistent
  double longitude;
  @Persistent
  double latitude;
  // simple 1:1 unidirectional
  @Persistent
  A      a;

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
  }

  public double getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
  }

  public void setA(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  public A getA() {
    return a;
  }
}
```

*Dao*

```
package dao;
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;
import javax.jdo.Transaction;

import jdotest.b.B;

public class BDao {
  public void write(B b) {
    PersistenceManagerFactory pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("cloud-sql");
    PersistenceManager pm = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
      tx.begin();
      pm.makePersistent(b);
      tx.commit();
    } finally {
      if (tx.isActive())
        tx.rollback();
      pm.close();
    }
  }
}
```

*execution*

```
  package exec;

  import jdotest.a.A;
  import jdotest.b.B;
  import dao.BDao;

  public class Ex{
    public void persist(){
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B();
      b.setA(a);
      new BDao().write(b); //<-- exception
    }
  }
```

- the exception *

  java.sql.SQLException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`xperimental`.`b`, CONSTRAINT `B_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`A_A_ID_OID`) REFERENCES `a` (`A_ID`))

Comment: suggest you post your actual code since all such examples in the JDO TCK all work, as they do in all of our tests. No idea what "identity type:application here to enable id lookups" means; you can do id lookups with datastore id or application id.

Comment: ah thanks, good to know that I can also to objectById lookup for DATASTORE identities as well (I did not get it right from docs). My comment "identity:type application.." I meant that I enforce IdentityType.APPLICATION when using a single field @PrimaryKey in a PC, I suppose when PC implies PrimaryKey it always be of identity IdentityType.APPLICATION?

Comment: @DataNucleus I've got a look on the tests, they unfortunately do not cover all permutations of available configuration options with JDO, I suppose they were written by someone who is very clear in DataNucleus implementation. DataNucleus cannot handle the above class configuration; I have to change these things: 1) class A has to provide a PrimaryKey field explicitely (I used long-type). 2) valueStrategy (for both PK fields) must not be NATIVE, I had to switch to IDENTITY in the case above. That fixed it. Did I disregard JDO' specification in my sample?

Comment: Obviously DataNucleus handles *all* such things, being the "reference implementation" for JDO, and I've no idea what you refer to as "the tests" ... the TCK ? one of the many DN unit test suites ? You still haven't provided your persistence code, and guesswork is not what Stackoverflow is about. I can run the exact code above, create A, B and persist the B and it works. I can do the same but persist an A and it works.

Comment: @DataNucleus I have updated all resources now, it simply does not work. I wonder how you can execute same code successfully?! I run  locally in GAE environment. You think there is something wrong with it?

Comment: I execute in real Java environment, not Cloud-SQL, using real MySQL. Your code is passing through Google's JDBC driver (presumably that is what "cloud-sql" persistence-unit is doing anyway), whatever that does. I, on the other hand, use the official JDBC driver from MySQL. Suggest you try it in a local MySQL env because it. works.

Comment: Maybe putting in some weird JDBC URL (such as jdbc:google:blahblah) is not picking up the MySQLAdapter (the log tells you), but then you can explicitly set which XXXAdapter is used

Comment: @DataNucleus its not about the wrong adapter, according to the logs the org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.adapter.MySQLAdapter is used. But the issue here is indeed with Google's CloudSQL driver. It also works for me with original MySql connector. Thanks for the hint. Maybe someone could fork MySqlAdapter to GoogleCloudSql fashion :)

Comment: Suggest you report whatever bug their JDBC driver has, think the project is at https://code.google.com/p/googlecloudsql/